# Trigger with two conditions is always triggered while one condition is false

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager

I have defined a trigger with two conditions of which both check whether variable is true.

It clearly states that "Fire this trigger when an Event occurs and all of these conditions are true".

I've checked that other one is False since it is supposed to return false after a certain date (way past today).

Why it is still triggered? Does it check that the variables are defined and not the actual values of variables and therefore returns true?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share more details about the trigger settings, preferably with a screenshot of the above mentioned conditions. Also, it would be useful to see the exact values of these variables from the GTM debug window.

Comment: Can you please use the preview mode an check the actual value of the variables. Most probably the variable you expect to be false is being true. If you need any help doing this just ask.

Comment: I'm using preview mode and just like I stated in the question that the variable value is False.